# How do I check whether I received access token in ASP.NET Core web app using Microsoft Identity Platform

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-identity-platform

My ASP.NET Core web app authenticates against Microsoft Identity Platform and calls a downstream API (Sharepoint) on behalf of the user.

I suspect that I'm not getting refresh tokens in the response from Microsoft Identity Platform.

How do I check, whether the refresh token is actually being sent to my app?

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
        {
            options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async e =>
            {

            };
            options.Events.OnTokenResponseReceived = async e =>
            {

            };
            options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async e =>
            {

            };
            options.Events.OnMessageReceived = async e =>
            {

            };
            configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Bind(options);
        })
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(scopes)
    .AddDistributedTokenCaches();
```

Comment: Hello Liero, could you kindly check the solution below, if it not helps, we can investigate the issue deeply together.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

```
"CallApi": {
    "ScopeForAccessToken": "offline_access User.Read [OtherScopes]"
}
```

Make sure we have add the necessary scope like above. Verify that the app has the right permissions and the user/admin has consented to those permissions.

And using below code to test again.

```
options.Events.OnTokenResponseReceived = async e =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"ID Token: {e.TokenEndpointResponse.IdToken}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {e.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Refresh Token: {e.TokenEndpointResponse.RefreshToken}");

};
```

---

You can use `TokenEndpointResponse.RefreshToken` to check if RefreshToken is exist or not.

```
string[]? initialScopes = configuration.GetValue<string>("CallApi:ScopeForAccessToken")?.Split(' ');

services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async e =>
    {

    };
    options.Events.OnTokenResponseReceived = async e =>
    {
        // Inspect the token response payload
        var refreshToken = e.TokenEndpointResponse.RefreshToken;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(refreshToken))
        {
            // Log or handle the absence of the refresh token
            e.HandleResponse();
            e.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            await e.Response.WriteAsync("Refresh token was not provided.");
        }
    };
    options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async e =>
    {

    };
    options.Events.OnMessageReceived = async e =>
    {

    };
    configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Bind(options);
})
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
.AddDistributedTokenCaches();
```

Comment: In the TokenEndpointResponse, all properties except IdToken are null

Comment: Hi @Liero, I have updated something, please check it, thanks

Comment: I'm sending offline_access, but not User.Read. Is User.Read required for refresh token?

Comment: Hi @Liero，not sure，but you can try it first.